# Js - Create a file and save it to a specific folder in the project

Tags: javascript, file

I created an excel file via javascript, but when I need to save it the only option is to have the user open the download window and download the file. I, on the other hand, would like the file to simply be stored in a folder in my project, without the user having the option to download the file.

How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: Is this in the browser? JavaScript has no control in the browser.

Comment: In a browser? Can't do, browsers run your code in something like a sandbox, you will never be able to access the underlying filesystem.

Comment: We can't directly access file system to store files without user consent because it can lead to potential security concern, what is some website try to save malware to local PC without user didn't know about. That's why browser JavaScript doesn't allow file system access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide enough information but seems that you are doing it on the client side (i.e. a browser), which, in principle, does not have access to the file system on your computer/server.

You should try some Back-end approach, like, in your case with JavaScript: Node.js, or maybe anothers like Python or PHP.

Comment: I will try some back-end approach